# How to add a sprite to a certain point in andengine?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am using this method to add a new sprite to my scene in andengine.

```
private void addBody(final float pX, final float pY) {
    final Scene scene = this.mEngine.getScene();
    if (BodyCount >= MAX_BODIES) return;
    BodyCount++;
    final Sprite matSprite;
    final Body body;
    if(BodyCount % 2 == 0) {
    matSprite = new Sprite(pX, pY,
    mTargetTextureRegion);
    body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld,
    matSprite, BodyType.DynamicBody,
    FIXTURE_DEF);
    } else {
    matSprite = new Sprite(pX, pY,
    mTargetTextureRegion);

    body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(
            mPhysicsWorld, matSprite,
            BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
            }
            scene.getLastChild().attachChild(matSprite);
            mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(
            new PhysicsConnector(matSprite, body, true, true));
            }
```

Here i call the method to add a body to the scene
but nothing happens. I log to see if the code is being ran and it returns true.

```
private void createSpriteSpawnTimeHandler(){
    TimerHandler spriteTimerHandler;
    float mEffectSpawnDelay = 1f;
    Random rand = new Random();

    final float x = (int) mCamera.getWidth() + mTargetTextureRegion.getWidth();
    int minY = mTargetTextureRegion.getHeight();
    int maxY = (int)(mCamera.getHeight() - mTargetTextureRegion.getHeight());
    int rangeY = maxY - minY; 
    final float y = rand.nextInt(rangeY) + minY;

    spriteTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(mEffectSpawnDelay,true,new ITimerCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            Log.e("MainGame", "Adding Body");
            addBody(x,y);

        }


    });
    getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(spriteTimerHandler);

}
```

What could the problem be? Or what is the best way to do this?
What i want to happen is the Sprites are added at the top of the screen and flow down the screen and then eventually off the screen.

Comment: When you say "nothing happens", do you mean you don't see anything happen visually? If the addBody method is being called, you might want to double check the (x,y) values you're passing it (are they off-screen perhaps?) and whether your sprite is being created properly (valid texture?) and added to the scene for rendering (if this doesn't happen automatically).

Comment: You are attaching your sprite to `scene.getLastChild()`. You might want to check if this is the entity you want to attach to. It looks like your x, y might be global, so maybe you just want to attach to `scene`.